# How can I change the color whenever I click the button?

Tags: javascript

When I click the button, I hope the body color is changed whenever I click

But It's only changed once.   If I click again , the color is not changed.

I don't know what did I have mistake on the code?

```js
let click = document.querySelector('.click');
let random_color = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);


click.addEventListener('click', () => {
  color();
})

function color() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = random_color;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<button class="click">click</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the random color variable form outside the `color()` function to inside the `color()` function.

This is the snippet:

```js
let click = document.querySelector('.click');

click.addEventListener('click', () => {
  color();
})

function color() {
  let random_color = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = random_color;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<button class="click">click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to generate a random color each click, which is contained in your `random_color` variable - yet you're setting that variable's value in stone and never updating it. You need to put it in the color() function to update each click.

I simplified the code a little here:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector('.click').addEventListener('click', () => color());
})

function color(e) {
  let random_color = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = random_color;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 90vh;
}
```

```html
<button class="click">click</button>
```